# What is the order of org-babel-do-load-languages and (package-initialize)

Tags: macos, emacs, babeljs

I have install `org` (package-list-packages), but the custom to supports `babel` is not easy. In my `.emacs`, there is `(package-initialize)` at begining, if i put `(org-babel-do-load-languages ...)` blow it, I get `Evaluation of this calc code block is disable`, while i put `(org-babel-do-load-languages ...)` before `(package-initialize)`, I can `C-c C-c` to evaluate the block code. But here it my problem, I found i can't use `C-c '` to type the code in another buff, i think maybe the code `(package-initialize)` is not effect in this situation. any suggestions?
The environment is mac-10.12.5, emacs-25.2.1, org-8.2.10.
PS：I have install the org-9.0.8, but the problem is still exists. Now, I have found the key problem, there are two version of org, the 8.2.10 can exec the babel block code, while the 9.0.8 cant, but why?

Comment: I have install the org-9.0.8, but the problem is still exists.

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are having: editing code blocks with `C-c '` or executing code blocks with `C-c C-c`? But when you start mentioning org-8 and org-9 in the same breath, it makes me think "mixed installation": you need to call `package-initialize` before emacs has a chance to autoload any org functions. See the note marked "Important" in the [Using Emacs packaging system](http://orgmode.org/manual/Installation.html#Installation) section of the manual.

Comment: BTW, the "Evaluation .. disabled" message rings a bell: I believe that there was some ELPA release of org that had a bug that caused this problem, but that was a month or two ago and it was fixed quickly: if 9.0.8 is the current release, it should not contain that bug You might want to post your problem on the Orgmode mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't really clear what your problem is or exactly how you are configuring
org-mode. Unfortunately, org-mode can be a little tricky because there is an
older version bundled with emacs 25.2 (8.x.x) and current package archives
contain later (9.x.x) versions.

The first thing you *must* do is ensure you are not getting a mixed version of
org-mode. Doing so is likely to cause some unexpected behaviour and odd
bugs. Either stick with the version of org mode included with Emacs or use a
later version installed via ELPA.

The critical step is that if you are installing via ELPA, you *must* make sure
that ELPA has installed and activated org mode *before* you load any org
functionality. In simplistic terms, the first reference to org should be in your
init code which installs org from ELPA.

Given that you seem to be fairly new to org and possibly new to emacs, my
recommendation would be to use the Emacs custom interface to configure org. This
will take care of some of the subtle things you need to do with some bits of the
org configuration and will likely provide an easier initial path to getting
started.

Unless there is functionality in version 9.x.x you need, I would also consider
just using the version of org which comes with emacs to begin with.

Start with a very plain (or even empty) init file, start emacs and then just do
M-x customize-group  org . You can then use the customize
interface to setup org.

Depending on what languages you need supported by babel, you may find you need
the org-plus-contrib package. In this case, you will need to add that package
via ELPA. I find the easiest way to manage this these days is to use the
use-package package. See github for details on use-package.

The basic idea is use package.el to install use-package and then use the
use-package package to install and configure all your other packages. There is a
little trick with the org-plus-contrib package - you need to specify the package
as org, but put org-plus-contrib in the :ensure key i.e.

```
(use-package org
  :ensure org-plus-contrib
  :init
  ;; stuff you want done before org loaded
  :config
  ;; stuff you want doen after org loaded
  )
```

,